# C program Debug Assertion Failed

Tags: c, assertions

I'm trying to implement an undo functionality for a C program. The problem is that I am getting Debug Assertion Failed (I marked the line). I am a begginer in C and I'll much appreciate your help. I hope is enought code in order to get this problem resolved.

Undo function from Controller.c

```
int undo(controller *ctr) {
    if (isEmpty(ctr->operationsStack)){
        return 0;
    }
    Operation operation = pop(ctr->operationsStack); //problem
    if (strcmp(getOperationType(&operation), "add") == 0) {
        materie mat = getMaterie(&operation);
        char nume[8];
        strcpy(nume, getNume(&mat));
        sterge(ctr->repo, nume);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Structures from OperationsStack.h

```
typedef struct
{
    materie mat;
    char operationType[10];
} Operation;

typedef struct
{
    Operation operations[100];
    int length;
} OperationsStack;
```

OperationsStack.c

```
Operation createOperation(materie planet, const char *operationType) {
    Operation operation;
    operation.mat = planet;
    strcpy(operation.operationType, operationType);
    return operation;
}

OperationsStack createStack() {
    OperationsStack operationsStack;
    operationsStack.length = 0;
    return operationsStack;
}

void push(OperationsStack *operationsStack, Operation operation) {
    if (isFull(operationsStack)) {
        return;
    }
    operationsStack->operations[operationsStack->length++] = operation;
}

Operation pop(OperationsStack *operationsStack) {
    if (isEmpty(operationsStack)) {
        materie mat;  //create a new 
        mat.cant = 0; //materie object 
        strcpy(mat.nume, " ");
        strcpy(mat.producator, " ");
        return createOperation(mat, "none"); 
    }
    else 
        return operationsStack->operations[--operationsStack->length];//problem
}

int isEmpty(OperationsStack *operationsStack) {
    return operationsStack->length == 0;
}
```

Let's suppose I add a materie type to my program. This means:

- OperationsStack.length = 1
- OperationsStack.operations is an operation type :
- OperationsStack.operations[0].operationType = "add"
- OperationsStack.operations[0].mat = ("name1","name2",2(random int number))
  Now I call undo and operation will get the result of pop function and this is the OperationsStack.operations[0] we have a few lines up. But here appears the error.

Comment: First of all, compile with warnings. Read them, try to understand them and fix the problem. Don't ignore them.

Comment: `if (isEmpty(&operationsStack))` → `if (isEmpty(operationsStack))`

Comment: Just saw that, I'm sorry. That was the only warning.

Comment: Ok. But it is difficult to find the problem. Could you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: I edited an example, I know it's not what your asked but I think it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It seems that I had a break in my program and this would end it call a function that would free a variable that was not allocated with malloc.